# 404 Page not found due to Nginx - MechBunny script

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, nginx-config

I have a website running on MechBunny tube script, and I only host this website on 1 dedicated server, running on Nginx. The script creator told me, I'll have to convert .htaccess file to nginx, otherwise the website will not work properly.

I also have in /etc/nginx/ the following:

```
/conf.d
/sites-available/MySite.com.conf
/sites-enabled/MySite.com.conf
```

My questions are:

1. is my nginx file correct?
2. where should I add this ng file?

Converted .htaccess file to Nginx:

```
# nginx configuration by winginx.com

autoindex off;

index index.php;

charset utf-8;

error_page 404 /404.php;

error_page 403 /403.php;

autoindex off;

location / {
  rewrite \.(gif|jpe?g|png) /image404.php break;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host$request_uri redirect;
}

location /ajax {
  rewrite ^/ajax/([a-z-]+)$ /core/ajax/$1.php break;
}

location = /filters {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=filters break;
}

location /page {
  rewrite ^/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&page=$1 break;
}

location /galleries {
  rewrite ^/galleries/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=gallery&id=$2;
}

location /video {
  rewrite ^/video/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=video&id=$2;
}

location /webcam {
  rewrite ^/webcam-video/(.*)-(.*).html$ /index.php?controller=video&id=$2&awe=1;
}

location = /signup {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=signup;
}

location = /tokens {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=tokens;
}

location = /validate {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=validate;
}

location = /upload_choose {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=upload_choose;
}

location = /upload {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=upload;
}

location = /upload_photo {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=upload&option=photo;
}

location = /login {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=login;
}

location = /logout {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=logout;
}

location = /contact {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=contact;
}

location /forgot {
  rewrite ^/forgot-pass$ /index.php?controller=forgot_pass;
}

location /my {
  rewrite ^/my-profile$ /index.php?controller=my_profile break;
  rewrite ^/my-friends$ /index.php?controller=my_friends;
  rewrite ^/my-friends/$ /index.php?controller=friends;
  rewrite ^/my-friends/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=friends&page=$1;
}

location /edit {
  rewrite ^/edit-profile$ /index.php?controller=edit_profile break;
  rewrite ^/edit-content/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=editContent&id=$1;
}

location /static {
  rewrite ^/static/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=displayStatic&id=$1;
}

location /load {
  rewrite ^/load/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=loadLayout&id=$1;
}

location /filter {
  rewrite ^/filter/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=setFilter&id=$1;
  rewrite ^/filter-content/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=setFilterContent&id=$1;
}

location = /unsetFilters {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=unsetMembersFilter break;
}

location /change {
  rewrite ^/change-colors$ /index.php?controller=changeColors;
}

location /embed {
  rewrite ^/embed/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?controller=embed&id=$1;
}

location = /404.php {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=404;
}

location = /403.php {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=403;
}

location /crss {
  rewrite ^/crss/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?controller=crss&id=$1;
}

location = /rss {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=rss;
}

location /a {
  rewrite ^/a/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=link&slug=$1;
}

location /webvtt {
  rewrite ^/webvtt/([0-9]+).vtt$ /index.php?controller=webvtt&id=$1;
}

location /purchase {
  rewrite ^/purchase/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?controller=rentVideo&id=$1;
}

location /buy {
  rewrite ^/buy-tokens$ /index.php?controller=buyTokens;
}

location /vr {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /my-uploads {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /favorites {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /most-recent {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /most-discussed {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /most-viewed {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /longest {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /top-rated {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /photos {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/photos/(most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|top-rated)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=photos&sortby=$1;
  rewrite ^/photos/(most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|top-rated)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=photos&sortby=$1;
}

location /random {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /my-friends {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /videos {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /my-rentals {
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(vr|my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends|videos|my-rentals)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
}

location /uploads {
  rewrite ^/uploads-by-user/([0-9]+)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=uploads-by-user&user=$1&dateRange=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/uploads-by-user/([0-9]+)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=uploads-by-user&user=$1&dateRange=$2;
  rewrite ^/uploads-by-user/([0-9]+)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=uploads-by-user&user=$1&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/uploads-by-user/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=uploads-by-user&user=$1;
}

location /search {
  rewrite ^/search/(videos|members|photos)/(.*)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&type=$1&q=$2&page=1&sortby=$3;
  rewrite ^/search/(videos|members|photos)/(.*)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&type=$1&q=$2&page=$4&sortby=$3;
  rewrite ^/search/(videos|members|photos)/(.*)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&type=$1&q=$2&page=1;
  rewrite ^/search/(videos|members|photos)/(.*)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&type=$1&q=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/search/(.*)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&q=$1&page=1&sortby=$2;
  rewrite ^/search/(.*)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&q=$1&page=$3&sortby=$2;
  rewrite ^/search/(.*)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&q=$1&page=1;
  rewrite ^/search/(.*)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&q=$1&page=$2;
}

location = /channels {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=channels;
}

location /channels {
  rewrite ^/channels/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=channel&channel=$1&sortby=$3;
  rewrite ^/channels/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?mode=channel&channel=$1&sortby=$3&page=$4;
  rewrite ^/channels/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=channel&channel=$1;
  rewrite ^/channels/([0-9]+)/(.*)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=channel&channel=$1&page=$3;
}

location = /paysites {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=paysites;
}

location /paysites {
  rewrite ^/paysites/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=paysites&paysite=$1&sortby=$3;
  rewrite ^/paysites/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?mode=paysites&paysite=$1&sortby=$3&page=$4;
  rewrite ^/paysites/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=paysites&paysite=$1;
  rewrite ^/paysites/([0-9]+)/(.*)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=paysites&paysite=$1&page=$3;
}

location /pornstars {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=pornstars;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(alphabetical|rating)/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&sortby=$2;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(alphabetical|rating)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&sortby=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)/(alphabetical|rating)/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$2&sortby=$3&page=1;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)/(alphabetical|rating)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$2&sortby=$3&page=$4;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstar_bio&id=$3 break;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$2&page=1;
}

location /models {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=pornstars;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(alphabetical|rating)/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&sortby=$2;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&page=$2;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(alphabetical|rating)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&sortby=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$2&page=$3;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)/(alphabetical|rating)/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$2&sortby=$3&page=1;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)/(alphabetical|rating)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$2&sortby=$3&page=$4;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstar_bio&id=$3 break;
  rewrite ^/(pornstars|models)/(.*)/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$2&page=1;
}

location = /mailbox {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /mailbox.php break;
}

location /mailbox {
  rewrite ^/mailbox/([0-9]+)$ /mailbox.php?mode=inbox&page=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/mailbox/inbox/([0-9]+)$ /mailbox.php?mode=inbox&page=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/mailbox/outbox/([0-9]+)$ /mailbox.php?mode=outbox&page=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/mailbox/read/([0-9]+)$ /mailbox.php?mode=read&mid=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/mailbox/read/([0-9]+)/delete/$ /mailbox.php?mode=read&mid=$1&delete=true;
  rewrite ^/mailbox/read/([0-9]+)/spam/$ /mailbox.php?mode=read&mid=$1&spam=true;
  rewrite ^/mailbox/compose/([0-9]+)/reply/$ /mailbox.php?mode=compose&mid=$1&reply=true;
}

location = /mailbox/inbox {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /mailbox.php?mode=inbox break;
}

location = /mailbox/outbox {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /mailbox.php?mode=outbox break;
}

location = /mailbox/compose {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /mailbox.php?mode=compose;
}

location /user {
  rewrite ^/user/(.*)-([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?controller=user_profile&id=$2;
}

location = /members {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=members;
}

location /members {
  rewrite ^/members/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=members&page=$1;
}

location = /tags {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=tags&page=1;
}

location /tags {
  rewrite ^/tags/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=tags&letter=$1;
}

location /online {
  rewrite ^/online-cams/$ /index.php?controller=aweonlinecams&page=1;
  rewrite ^/online-cams/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=aweonlinecams&page=$1;
}

location /live {
  rewrite ^/live-webcams/loadMaster/(.*)$ /includes/ajax.aweblacklabel_loadmaster.php?id=$1;
  rewrite ^/live-webcams/loadModel/(.*)$ /includes/ajax.aweblacklabel_loadmodel.php?id=$1;
  rewrite ^/live-webcams/loadVideos/(.*)$ /includes/ajax.aweblacklabel_loadvideos.php?id=$1;
  rewrite ^/live-webcams/loadGalleries/(.*)$ /includes/ajax.aweblacklabel_loadgalleries.php?id=$1;
  rewrite ^/live-webcams/loadRecommended/(.*)$ /includes/ajax.aweblacklabel_loadrecommended.php?id=$1;
  rewrite ^/live-webcams/loadMore/(.*)$ /includes/ajax.aweblacklabel_loadmore.php?listPageId=$1;
  rewrite ^/live-webcams/paymentCallback$ /index.php?controller=aweblacklabel&paymentCallback=1;
  rewrite ^/live-webcams/$ /index.php?controller=aweblacklabel&page=1;
  rewrite ^/live-webcams/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=aweblacklabel&page=$1;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to convert htaccess to nginx also there a lot of think's you can do it by one Location Block and you forget the server and server_name and fastcgi you see [Creating NGINX Rewrite Rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)